# Correct method of querying a distinct list of a string field using repository pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I would like to select a distinct list of a `string` field to make it possible for the user to select one and filter the `Entities`  this way .

What is the best practice to do so using the pattern in the correct way?

For example I have this class:

```
public class A
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public int a1 { set; get; }
    public string a2 { set; get; }
    public int a3 { set; get; }
}
```

Is this interface correct, or should I do this some other way?

```
public interface IARepository
{
    A Select(int id);
    IList<A> SelectAll();
    void Delete(int id);
    void Update(A selection);
    void Insert(A selection);

    IList<String> SelectDistinctA2();   // <-- are these 2 lines correct?
    IList<A> SelectAllByA2(string a2);  // <--
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've thought in another possible approach:

```
public class A
{
    public int id { set; get; }
    public int a1 { set; get; }
    public A2 a2 { set; get; }
    public int a3 { set; get; }
}

public class A2
{
    public string text { set; get; }
}

public interface IARepository
{
    A Select(int id);
    IList<A> SelectAll();
    void Delete(int id);
    void Update(A selection);
    void Insert(A selection);

    IList<A> SelectAllByA2(A2 a2);  // or IList<A> SelectAllByA2(string a2Text);  
}

public interface IA2Repository
{
    IList<A2> SelectDistinctA2();          
}
```